# ThreadLocal<T> Documentation in JDK

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local-storage

JDK 1.6 documentation shows an example about how to use `LocalThread<T>`. I copy and paste it here:

For example, the class below generates unique identifiers local to each thread. A thread's id is assigned the first time it invokes `UniqueThreadIdGenerator.getCurrentThreadId()` and remains unchanged on subsequent calls.

```
 import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger; 

 public class UniqueThreadIdGenerator {    
     private static final AtomicInteger uniqueId = new AtomicInteger(0);    
     private static final ThreadLocal <Integer> uniqueNum = 
         new ThreadLocal <Integer> () {
             @Override 
             protected Integer initialValue() {
                 return uniqueId.getAndIncrement();
         }
     };

     public static int getCurrentThreadId() {
         return uniqueId.get();
     }
 } // UniqueThreadIdGenerator
```

My problem is:

when multiple threads call `UniqueThreadIdGenerator.getCurrentThreadId()` it only returns 0 because there is no initialization. Shouldn't it be like this:

```
public static int getCurrentThreadId() {
    return uniqueNum.get();
}
```

Now after the first call, it goes and initialize the variable.

Comment: Instead of generating a unique id, you could use the unique id each thread has already.

    `long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it should be `uniqueNum.get()`. The [JDK 7 docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) get it right, and use better names:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ThreadId {
    // Atomic integer containing the next thread ID to be assigned
    private static final AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger(0);

    // Thread local variable containing each thread's ID
    private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> threadId =
        new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
            @Override protected Integer initialValue() {
                return nextId.getAndIncrement();
        }
    };

    // Returns the current thread's unique ID, assigning it if necessary
    public static int get() {
        return threadId.get();
    }
}
```

It's not really a matter of *initialization* though - it's simply a matter of using the wrong member entirely. Even if lots of code *had* used `uniqueNum` in the original code, `getCurrentThreadId()` would always have returned "the next ID to be assigned" instead of "the ID assigned for the current thread".

Comment: Perhaps one should also override ThreadLocal's `set` and `remove` methods and throw an [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html). Just a thought.